# Power Query for Excel

Tags: excel, dns, salesforce, powerquery

I need some help with adjusting this Power Query for Excel. Specifically I need to connect it with Salesforce but there are 2 issues I am facing:

1. My Company is using SSO (Single Sing-on) for login, meaning we are not asked any password/username; but just click on main access button to enter the salesforce.
2. We are using a special domain, i.e. CompanyName.my.salesforce.com which doesn't seem to work for this Microsoft Power Query Add-in.

Does anybody know a clear workaround or have you faced this kind of problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the domain federated for use? If so, I'd think it'd just work through with SAML

Comment: Sorry, I am new at this. May I ask what does this mean exactly? Can I still use PQ anyhow? Thanks!

Comment: Our company has both SSO and the same special domain and I have no problems. What version of Excel are you in? Is it 2010/13 with the PLugin or 2016 with the 'Get Data' tab? Are you trying to connect and get Salesforce Objects or Salesforce Reports. Do you get directed to the SFDC login screen? If so, do you click the 'Custom Domain' link before clicking the SSO sign in button?? I have had no issues in both 2013 with the Plugin and also 2016 with Get Data.